# Как вывести таблицу из базы данных в Excel файл с использованием Python. Ошибка

Tags: python, sql, excel

Работа ведется в Eclipse на Debian

Для вывода таблицы из базы данных в Excel файл, использую следующий скрипт на Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: <utf-8> -*-

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pymysql
import pandas as pd

db_host = "localhost"
db_user = "root"
db_pwd = "password"
db_name = "myWork" 
db_charset = "utf8mb4"

db_connection = f"mysql+pymysql://{db_user}:{db_pwd}@{db_host}/{db_name}?charset={db_charset}"
conn = create_engine(db_connection)

df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM Students", conn)
print(df)

df.to_excel("/path/to/table_name.xlsx", index=False)
```

Выдает ошибку

```
  File "/home/user/eclipse-workspace/test/test.py", line 13
  db_connection = f"mysql+pymysql://{db_user}:{db_pwd}@{db_host}/{db_name}?charset={db_charset}"
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Как исправить проблему?

Comment: `db_connection = f".."`

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev выдает ошибку   File "/home/user/eclipse-workspace/test/test.py", line 13
    db_connection = f"mysql+pymysql://{db_user}:{db_pwd}@{db_host}/{db_name}?charset={db_charset}"
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: А, ну правильно, Python 2.7 не поддерживает интерполяцию строк. Придётся вам `db_connection` собирать конкатенацией.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Хм... Я не знаю что это такое. Новичок в изучении Python и SQL

Comment: `db_connection = "mysql+pymysql://" + db_user + ":" + db_pwd + "@" + db_host + "/" + db_name + "?charset=" + db_charset`

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev спасибо помогло!